# Node.js GLIBC Compatibility Issue on Ubuntu - How to Resolve?"

Tags: node.js, angularjs, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, glibc

The error message indicates that the Node.js version I'm trying to use is not compatible with the GLIBC library version installed on my Ubuntu system, requiring me to either update GLIBC, use a different Node.js version.

This is the first time I've seen this. My Angular Cli requires node 18.13 but this GLIBC requires node. It's giving me the biggest headache. Any tips?

I'm using angular, AWS code commit, AWS EC2 and S3 bucket for images. Macbook pro 2021

```
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
```